# How to rollbacktrain when an insert fails and is null in Spring Boot JPA?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

have a problem in my spring boot thesis:
I want to find the syntax rollbacktrain when an insert fails, it will roll back all. I searched google but it came back to Rollbacktrain when an error occurred.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/addOne", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Object addOne(@RequestHeader("tokenAC") String token, @RequestBody ModelToaThuoc modelToaThuoc)
        throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException {
        boolean result = authenticationService.xacThucUser(token);
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        if (result) {
            System.out.println("toa Thuoc: " + modelToaThuoc.getClass());
            Date ngay = new Date();
            modelToaThuoc.getToaThuoc().setNgay_ke_toa(ngay);
            ToaThuoc toaThuoc = modelToaThuoc.getToaThuoc(); 
            toaThuoc = toaThuocService.saveOne(toaThuoc);
            //thêm chi tiết thuốc vào
            if(toaThuoc!= null) {
                List<ChiTietToaThuoc> ChiTietToaThuocs = modelToaThuoc.getListChiTietToaThuoc();
                for(ChiTietToaThuoc oneChiTietToaThuoc : ChiTietToaThuocs) {
                //if insert at here null I will rool back all but i don't syntax, please help me, thanks you
                     chiTietThuocService.save(oneChiTietToaThuoc);
                }
                return ChiTietToaThuocs ;
            }
            return toaThuoc;
        }
        map.put("statusCode", 404);
        return map;
}
```

Comment: Move all the processing logic to a Service method annotated with `@Transactional` and throw a RunTimeException (or some other exception which triggers a rollback) `@Transactional(rollbackFor = MyCheckedException.class)`. A better solution is to validate the incoming data at the Controller level before you start processing it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did as you said right after posting this question. I sincerely apologize for not posting my answers sooner.

Comment: This is what I did right after I posted the question and it worked.